# Is there an official redirector for Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, software-sources, mirrors

I would like to know if there is an official redirector for Ubuntu like Debian's [httpredir.debian.org](http://httpredir.debian.org/).

As I searched on Google, I found something on the [Ubuntu Mailing Lists](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-community-team/2015-September/000779.html) that was related to this, but no answer.

I also found mirrors.ubuntu.com, but I have no idea how to use it as a redirector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Searching on Google, it appears that there is no official redirector currently.**

`mirrors.ubuntu.com` can be used as a redirector (sort-of), by using it in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. For example, you can replace the following lines:

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

with these lines:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial main restricted
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial main restricted
```

You can perform the change for all the lines that use a specific mirror (`fr.archive.ubuntu.com` in my example). Do not perform the change for `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` as it is important it remains as it is for urgent security releases (bypassing mirror delays).

**Note:** `/etc/apt/sources.list` is an important file. Make a backup copy before you edit it. You need to edit it as root (or rather, edit a copy as a regular user, then put the edited copy back into `/etc/apt` as root).

Note also that this `mirror` method sometimes failed in recent Ubuntu releases. I may have been fixed in 16.04, but the bug is still open: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1479045

Comment: "I think this has been fixed in apt 1.1 in 16.04 or at least I haven't seen this issue in a long time."
So, it is probably fixed, but I will be careful and use 16.10. Thanks!